# Loading sample data in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

When a user creates a new account on my site, I'd like to load sample data into his account. I would have done this easily with fixtures, but the problem is that the sample data needs to know the new account ID, so I need to pass this to the fixtures, but I don't know if it's possible.

That's my idea, but I am open to other best way to load sample data into DB for new account users.

Comment: actually one more problem with fixtures is they seem to wipe out any existing data.

Answer (score 1):

oh okay, i found the solution to my problem, xianese of http://xianese.blogspot.com/2008/05/use-yaml-to-load-sample-data-into.html have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Fixtures but I think it's really just for testing your application.

I haven't tested it yet but I would recommend you something like [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl). It's pretty straightforward to use and in combination with [FFaker](https://github.com/ffaker/ffaker) the best solution to generate sample data.

Hope this helps!

Happy coding :)